# "Who has" or "Who have" when referring to a collection of people in a department

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english, relative-pronouns

> - I have spoken with Education Unit who has requested a contract.
> - I have spoken with Education Unit who have requested a contract.

Which of the above is most acceptable in British English?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think 'which have requested a contract' would make sense to a sound grammarian?

Comment: @Andy: Not sure what "make sense" means there. The *meaning* is the same (and obvious) in all variations, but I personally wouldn't accept *I spoke to the department **which have** my records*, for example, and ***who has*** is just as bad there. As I implied, singular ***which has*** is fine by me - but I'm perfectly happy with plural ***who have*** as well.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate, because the BrE answer there gives the answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant, if the usage would be acceptable by saying if it'd make sense to a grammarian. A simple answer that problem is using the that determiner. That have, that has are in no contradiction with good writing style.

Comment: @Andy: Nobody mentioned "that" before. I was simply making the point that the acceptability of "who" and "which" depends partly on plurality (besides "antropomorphization")..

Comment: Point taken and I think I've given an answer to the conundrum arising out of the said determiners.

Answer (score 0):

I think, based on [this, see 5.3.3](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tjrd5UnFT2gC&pg=PT42#v=onepage&q&f=false), that the 2nd might be preferred in BrE/BE by some, but there's quite a variability from a speaker to another. See the 2nd para wrt lack of consistency.

Comment: No, I believe the first is unacceptable in all varieties of English. If you use  *who*, then you have to use *have*, even in American English. (Unless *the Education Unit* is a job title for a single person.)

Comment: @Peter Shor great point, I kind of missed that "who."